# Get table column names and the values

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, oracle, linq

I have a table and some of that columns i need to take it to my dropdown list.and i need to show that values in dropdown list also.In my idea i get that column name to the dropdownlist Text field and that numbers to the dropdown list value filed.

My Dropdown i need to looks like this.(this is for userId 100)
[image]

**My Table.**
[image]

This is Oracle database and i tried to get it both text and value looks like this.. but unfortunately.. i cant get the value.( eg.. if Volvo has 3 ).

> > In here using below query i can get that Column names,But i need both column names and respective values.

My Code

```
public List<AllocModel> GetAllocationByUserId(string UserId)
    {
        try
        {
            DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
            Database db = factory.Create("DefaultCon");
            con.Open();

            string Query = @"SELECT column_name
                             FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
                             WHERE table_name = 'TBL_ALLOC' AND column_name LIKE 'EZ_%'";

           // string Query = @"SELECT column_name
                          //   FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS T ,TBL_ALLOC TX
                          //   WHERE T.table_name = 'TBL_ALLOC' AND T.column_name LIKE 'EZ_%' AND (TX.UserId =: TX.UserId)";

            cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(Query);

           // db.AddInParameter(cmd, "TX.UserId", DbType.String, UserId);

            var dx = db.ExecuteDataSet(cmd);

            var dd = dx.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => new AllocModel
            {
                 COLUMN_NAME = x.Field<string>("COLUMN_NAME") // Column names comes to here.
            });

            var allocNos = dd.ToList();
            return allocNos;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, you expected result like this? --> Volvo (3)

Comment: Yes.i need that result.

Comment: @Webster I can get Volvo name but can't get (3).. i need to change the query... This is Oracle

Comment: This is a bad table design.  You should have a table somewhere that lists your car makes, and *a single column* in your table above that specifies the make key to your car makes table.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hi robert,this is not the bad design,but this EZ columns created from another application and use it for another purpose.

Comment: What do the numbers mean?

Comment: @RobertHarvey numbers means as a example if it's a Volvo then it's 3

Comment: I have to agree with @RobertHarvey.  This has bad design written all over it.  The table shown, quite simply, does not meet Third Normal Form.  The fact that it may have been created from another app simply means that other app and the "other purposes" is also badly designed.  I'd also question the OP's need for getting both column name and some value together in the drop-down.  We don't know how that is to be used but it is another big red flag that the wrong technique is being used to solve some unknown (to us) business problem.

Comment: also asked at https://community.oracle.com/thread/3895274?sr=inbox&ru=763581

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Oracle Concatenate Syntax](http://www.sqlbook.com/SQL/SQL-CONCATENATE-24.aspx) to join columns.

You can use this

```
 string Query = @"SELECT column_A || '(' || EZ_Volvo || ')' ||
                             FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
                             WHERE table_name = 'TBL_ALLOC' AND column_name LIKE 'EZ_%'";
```

Comment: But in here EZ_Volvo is hardcoded know ? then what is column_A ?